# Azure Web jobs run multiple times on the provided cron pattern

Tags: cron, azure-webjobs

I have this CRON pattern for my web jobs 0 0/12 20 * * * and it's running every 12 hours starting 8PM. now the problem is that in azure the service run for almost 5 times until 9PM. is there a way that it should only run once?

Comment: what do you mean of only run once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cron expression means it starts from 8pm and every runs 12 minutes. Cause the azure timer binding document couldn't be open for now, you could refer to this wiki: [TimerTrigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/README.md#timertrigger).

There are six fields `{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day of the week}` to schedule.

So in your situation if you want to run every 12 hours starting 8PM. Yo could try this cron: `0 0 20/12 * * *` or with this one `0 0 8,20 * * *`. One is start from 8pm and every 12 hours and one is run at the specified time.

Comment: Right. i see. thanks for answering my question. I used this 0 0 8,20 * * * pattern and it works.